# Why can't I use routers in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, mobx-react

I am a bit confused on how to use react-router v4. The last time I used it I used v2 and it wasn't so different. I tried to follow some tutorials but I can't get it to work.

I get these two errors:

```
app.bundle.js:358 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

app.bundle.js:304 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
    at invariant (app.bundle.js:304)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (app.bundle.js:17635)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (app.bundle.js:32634)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (app.bundle.js:32525)
    at Object.mountComponent (app.bundle.js:4197)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (app.bundle.js:32638)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (app.bundle.js:32525)
    at Object.mountComponent (app.bundle.js:4197)
    at mountComponentIntoNode (app.bundle.js:18399)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (app.bundle.js:6742)
```

My app looks like this right now:

```
import {BrowseRouter, Route, Switch, HashRouter} from 'react-router'

import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider {... stores}>
        <HashRouter>
            <MyComponent />
        </HashRouter>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I tried both `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter` but same problems arises in both cases. I am using MobX which might be what is causing the problem. If I remove the routing stuff my component loads. How do I get this router stuff working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that`BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter` are both part of the package [`react-router-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) -- not the core `react-router` (a change in v4) thus importing them from `react-router` will make them undefined thus the error when you try to create an element from undefined.

A huge change in v4 was to separate the different bindings for React Router into separate packages for organization, `react-router-dom` for DOM bindings, `react-router-native` for React Native bindings, etc, with `react-router` holding only the core. `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter` are *DOM bindings*, thus the exist in the `react-router-dom` package.

`Switch` and `Route` also come from `react-router-dom` so import them from `react-router-dom`:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: ah makes sense I started out copying my old v2 code. I also found this package for mbox https://github.com/alisd23/mobx-react-router#usage . I got the routing to sort of work Where I have 2 buttons and each button shows a diff component and that works but for whatever reason back button does not work(url changes but old component does not load). Not sure what advantage this package has over just using the router package. I will post that code also.

Comment: @chobo2 I'm not familiar with MobX myself but it seems to assist with syncing the store with React Router, much like `react-router-redux` for Redux.

Comment: Hmm, yea I don't understand what that really means 100% I know stores have my code and keep track of my state of what they are doing but what is it keeping track of that react router would not be doing already?

Comment: @chobo2 I'm really sorry I can't help in that area as I'm not familiar at all with MobX. Also, if you have a new question, please don't ask it here. Ask it in a new question so others can help.

Comment: Ok, tried what you said that was the problem though the routing does not but my page does not crash. If I do <Route path='/component1' component={Component1}/> and <Link to='/one'>Component1</Link> nothing happens, url changes but component is not loaded up might be becasue I am using mobx?

Comment: @chobo2 Shouldn't it be `<Link to='/component1'>...</Link>`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. But still not getting anything to work. I must be missing something as I went back to using the other plugin and now I get the same problem.

Comment: @chobo2 Again, I can't help much further than React Router itself. Since the question was about React Router, I answered but I can't help much further than that.